# Grails 2.3.0 upgrade issue with windows slashes

Tags: windows, grails, unicode, upgrade, backslash

While upgrading an existing application (recently upgraded, and working, with Grails 2.2.4), I upgraded the common module (referred to as myApp-common) used in the two components of the application. This proceeded smoothly, but when I attempted to upgraded the first dependent module, I received this stacktrace attached when running the "grails upgrade" command.

> | Environment set to development.....
>
> ```
>     WARNING: This target will upgrade an older Grails application to 2.3.0.
>     Are you sure you want to continue?
>                [y,n] y
> ```
>
> | Executing myApp-common plugin upgrade script
>   | Error Error executing script Upgrade: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>   General error during parsing: Did not find four digit hex character code. line: 1 col:20
>
> groovyjarjarantlr.TokenStreamIOException: Did not find four digit hex character code. line: 1 col:20
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyLexer.nextToken(GroovyLexer.java:723)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyLexer$1.nextToken(GroovyLexer.java:258)
>           at groovyjarjarantlr.TokenBuffer.fill(TokenBuffer.java:69)
>           at groovyjarjarantlr.TokenBuffer.LA(TokenBuffer.java:80)
>           at groovyjarjarantlr.LLkParser.LA(LLkParser.java:52)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.nls(GroovyRecognizer.java:793)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.varInitializer(GroovyRecognizer.java:2681)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.variableDeclarator(GroovyRecognizer.java:7928)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.listOfVariables(GroovyRecognizer.java:7882)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.variableDefinitions(GroovyRecognizer.java:2278)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.declaration(GroovyRecognizer.java:2140)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1208)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:666)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:131)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:527)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:516)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:556)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:527)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:72)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:252)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at Upgrade$_run_closure1.doCall(Upgrade.groovy:229)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
>           at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
>           at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
>           at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
>           at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:730)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1150)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
>           at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
>           at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
>           at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
>           at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>           at Upgrade$_run_closure2.doCall(Upgrade.groovy:239)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
>           at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
>           at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
>           at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
>           at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:730)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1150)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
>           at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>           at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>           at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>           at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>           at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
>           at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
>           at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>           at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
>           at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
>           at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:732)
>           at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
>           at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
>           at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:773)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:571)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:470)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:414)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:378)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:226)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
>
> 1 error
>    (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

After some googling, it looked like this was related to a known issue with having \u in the code when not followed by a hex code. After removing all instances thereof, it still gave the same error. Next I changed the workspace where the code was at the time from C:\unique_workspace\Iteration21 to C:\x_unique_workspace\Iteration21 to remove the \u in the workspace address. Doing this and attempting the upgrade again resulted in this stacktrace:

> | Environment set to development.....
>
> ```
>     WARNING: This target will upgrade an older Grails application to 2.3.0.
>     Are you sure you want to continue?
>                [y,n] y
> ```
>
> | Executing myApp-common plugin upgrade script
>   | Error Error executing script Upgrade: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

```
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1, column 20.
def pluginDir = 'C:\x_unique_workspace\Iteration21\myApp-common'
                   ^
```

> 1 error
>    (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

```
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1, column 20.
def pluginDir = 'C:\x_unique_workspace\Iteration21\myApp-common'
                   ^
```

> 1 error
>
> ```
>    at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:72)
>     at Upgrade$_run_closure1.doCall(Upgrade.groovy:229)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
>     at Upgrade$_run_closure2.doCall(Upgrade.groovy:239)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>     at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>     at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
>     at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
>     at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
>     at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
>     at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
>     at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>     at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
>     at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
>     at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
>     at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
>     at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
> ```
>
> | Error Error executing script Upgrade: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

```
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1, column 20.
def pluginDir = 'C:\x_unique_workspace\Iteration21\myApp-common'
                   ^
```

It appears that the upgrade script is choking on the '\' character while it updates the common plugin that the module requires, but I am having trouble discerning a way around it.

Comment: Can you put the concise summary at the _top_ of this wall of text rather than the bottom?

Comment: Do you have `def pluginDir = 'C:\x_unique_workspace\Iteration21\myApp-common'` or the properly escaped `def pluginDir = 'C:\\x_unique_workspace\\Iteration21\\myApp-common'` in your file?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when trying to perform an upgrade (spring-security-core plugin). I added the following property to my BuildConfig.groovy to fix it:

```
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.plugins.dir = "${grails.project.work.dir}/plugins"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the `upgrade` command. Instead of running `grails upgrade` manually change the `app.grails.version=2.3.x` line in the application.properties file in your Project's directory.

See the [JIRA issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10863)

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the empty file of `/scripts/_upgrade.groovy`. It has // or commonented lines, so you could try deleting this file.

Comment: This is what happened in my case, `plugins\jquery-1.8.3\_Upgrade.groovy` was all commented out causing that error message. Deleting that file fixed the problem